# Hide UISearchBar until user scrolls?

Tags: ios, ios6, uisearchbar

I implemented a search bar and search display controller on top of my table view.

When the view loads the search bar and relative scopes are always visible.

Is there a simple way to hide it until the user scrolls down, like it happens in the Music app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add search bar as a header of the table view and then set the `contentoffset` property of table view in `viewDidLoad` as,

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,44) animated:YES];//or (0, 88) depends on the height of it
```

For search display controller, you can try this as well,

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: The solution doesn't hide the search bar when all the rows in the table fit on the screen. Any known workarounds for this type of scenario?

Comment: @Zorayr: Have you found a working solution for Tables where the Cells fit in the whole screen? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 12):

another approach without hardcode

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 7):

After a few hours of hair pulling, something that works

- on iOS 9
- doesn't depend on the number of rows in the table
- with variable height rows

  Considering the searchbar is the tableView.tableHeaderView

  ```
  @interface MyTableViewController ()

  @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL firstLayout;

  @end

  - (void) viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];


  self.firstLayout = YES;
  //your code

  }

  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  if(self.firstLayout){
  CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top);
  [self.tableView setContentOffset:offset];

      self.firstLayout = NO;

  }

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

for iOS 7 and using `UINavigationController`

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.searchBar.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way i did reload tableview in

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];     
    [self performSelector:@selector(reload:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}

- (void)reload:(__unused id)sender {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    } else {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works fine on iOS9+

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
    });
}
```